# Ein mearvim simcha besimcha - two shevah brochos in one meal

Tags: blessing, sheva-brachos

I would like to hear of any sources or issues with conducting two *shevah brachos* (for two couples) at the same meals:

1. Would it be *assur* because of *"ein Mearvin"*
2. How would it be done practically.

thanks

Comment: I know Rav Moshe Feinstein discusses two weddings together... would have to see his analysis there. Interesting question!

Comment: thanks, anyone with access to his books? Is there an online database of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch discusses this in Even HaEzer 62:2-3. In short, one can marry multiple women at one Chuppah ceremony and say one set of Sheva Brachot for all of them together. If one does this, he must have separate subsequent celebratory periods for each of the women individually (because of "ein mearvin"). If there are multiple weddings happening together, it is theoretically permitted to reciter one Sheva Brachot for all of them, but we don't do this because of Ayin Hara. However, if there are multiple bridegrooms at one celebratory meal, one may say one set of Sheva Brachot for all of them together.